# Add attributes value using foreach in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Below is my XSLT structure and I am trying to add the `(EARNEDINCOMEAMOUNT * PAYMENTFREQUENCYTYPE)` for each `EARNEDINCOME` node.

XSLT structure:

```
<EMPLOYMENT CUSTOMERNUMBER="1001349" CUSTOMERVERSIONNUMBER="31"  EMPLOYMENTSEQUENCENUMBER="2" EMPLOYMENTSTATUS="110" >  
  <EARNEDINCOME CUSTOMERNUMBER="1001349" CUSTOMERVERSIONNUMBER="31" EMPLOYMENTSEQUENCENUMBER="2" EARNEDINCOMESEQUENCENUMBER="1" EARNEDINCOMEAMOUNT="1142" PAYMENTFREQUENCYTYPE="12" PAYMENTFREQUENCYTYPE_TEXT="Monthly" />  
  <EARNEDINCOME CUSTOMERNUMBER="1001349" CUSTOMERVERSIONNUMBER="31" EMPLOYMENTSEQUENCENUMBER="2" EARNEDINCOMESEQUENCENUMBER="2" EARNEDINCOMEAMOUNT="4960" PAYMENTFREQUENCYTYPE="12" PAYMENTFREQUENCYTYPE_TEXT="Monthly" />
</EMPLOYMENT>
```

What I have tried so far is.

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//EARNEDINCOME">
    <xsl:attribute name="GROSSINCOME">
    <xsl:value-of select="(EARNEDINCOME[@EMPLOYMENTSEQUENCENUMBER=$vSequenceNumber]/@EARNEDINCOMEAMOUNT * EARNEDINCOME[@EMPLOYMENTSEQUENCENUMBER=$vSequenceNumber]/@PAYMENTFREQUENCYTYPE)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="@EARNEDINCOMEAMOUNT*@PAYMENTFREQUENCYTYPE"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:for-each>
```

What is get out of this is just multiplication of each node but I am not able to add it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to get the desired sum based on the XSLT version being used.

**XSLT 2.0** allows using the XPath in the `sum()` function so the below code will provide the desired output.

```
<xsl:template match="EMPLOYMENT">
    <SOMENODE>
        <xsl:attribute name="GROSSINCOME">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(EARNEDINCOME/(@EARNEDINCOMEAMOUNT * @PAYMENTFREQUENCYTYPE))" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </SOMENODE>
</xsl:template>
```

**XSLT 1.0** does not provide a simple way to achieve this. If using XSLT 1.0, you will have write a recursive template call which will do the product for every node and then keep on adding them for all the nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="EMPLOYMENT">
    <SOMENODE>
        <xsl:attribute name="GROSSINCOME">
            <xsl:call-template name="ProductSum">
                <xsl:with-param name="earnedIncome" select="*" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </SOMENODE>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ProductSum">
    <xsl:param name="earnedIncome" />
    <xsl:param name="sum" select="0" />

    <xsl:variable name="nodeStart" select="$earnedIncome[1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="nodeEnd" select="$earnedIncome[position() > 1]" />
    <xsl:variable name="currSum" select="$nodeStart/@EARNEDINCOMEAMOUNT * $nodeStart/@PAYMENTFREQUENCYTYPE" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not($nodeEnd)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$sum + $currSum" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <!-- Recursive call to the same template -->
            <xsl:call-template name="ProductSum">
                <xsl:with-param name="earnedIncome" select="$nodeEnd" />
                <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + $currSum" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Using **EXSLT (Extension functions)** - If using XSLT 1.0 and if you can use extension functions, the `node-set()` function can be used.

```
<xsl:template match="/EMPLOYMENT">
    <!-- create a variable to store the EARNEDINCOME nodes along 
         with a new attribute ANNUALINCOME that has the product 
         of the attributes -->
    <xsl:variable name="nodes">
        <xsl:for-each select="EARNEDINCOME">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <!-- add a new attribute to EARNEDINCOME node -->
                <xsl:attribute name="ANNUALINCOME">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@EARNEDINCOMEAMOUNT * @PAYMENTFREQUENCYTYPE" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <SOMENODE>
        <xsl:attribute name="GROSSINCOME">
            <!-- use the node-set function to compute the sum
                 of this new attribute from the above variable -->
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(exslt:node-set($nodes)/EARNEDINCOME/@ANNUALINCOME)" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </SOMENODE>
</xsl:template>
```

All the XSLTs will give the same output

```
<SOMENODE GROSSINCOME="73224"/>
```