# XSL How can I do a odds program using sum into a foreach?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a question. How can I make a summation of the results of a `<xsl:for-each>`? The result has to appear only once. This is what appears to me: "0.1, 0.3" but I want the sum of these values.

I tried to put everything in one variable, but I do not get anything out, I guess it does not let me put variables into other variables.
So, what can I do?

XML

```
<datos>
    <arbol nbarbol="Tiendas" n="100">
        <atributo nbatributo="Tiendas">
            <valor nbvalor="TiendaA" f="70">
                <atributo>
                    <valor nbvalor="ProductoA" f="10" encendido="1"></valor>
                    <valor nbvalor="ProductoB" f="20" encendido="0"></valor>
                    <valor nbvalor="ProductoC" f="30" encendido="1"></valor>
                </atributo>
            </valor>
        </atributo>
    </arbol>
</datos>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="descendant::valor">
            <xsl:variable name="instancias">
                <xsl:value-of select="@encendido" />
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:if test="$instancias='1'">
                <xsl:variable name="probadatos">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@f div ../../@f" />
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:value-of select="($probadatos) * (../../@f div ../../../../@n)" />
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Looking at your calculations, your expression in the xsl:value-of is of the form `(A div B) * (B div C)`, which simplifies to just `(A div C)`. As C is the same for each `valor` you don't need to use a xsl:for-each here or try to sum computed values. You can just do `<xsl:value-of select="sum(//valor[@encendido='1']/@f) div */*/@n" />`. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWmuiJ7

Comment: thak you so much! I didn't think on that!  thank's again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summation of a computational value using `XSLT 1.0` is slightly cumbersome since XSLT 1.0 does not allow usage of XPath in `sum()` function. If you have the liberty to upgrade to `XSLT 2.0` processor, it will be much easier for you to perform the summation of the computation using the `sum()` function.

However, if you do not have the option and have to work with `XSLT 1.0`, then you will have to use a recursive template call that will perform the computation and then keep on the adding all the computations to generate the final sum.

Below is the XSLT that will help.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" exclude-result-prefixes="xalan">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="arbol">
        <xsl:variable name="n" select="@n" />
        <xsl:variable name="f" select="atributo/valor/@f" />
        <xsl:for-each select="atributo/valor/atributo">
            <summation>
                <xsl:call-template name="ProductSum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="nodeSet" select="*" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="f" select="$f" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </summation>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ProductSum">
        <xsl:param name="nodeSet" />
        <xsl:param name="n" />
        <xsl:param name="f" />
        <xsl:param name="sum" select="0" />

        <xsl:variable name="nodeStart" select="$nodeSet[1]" />
        <xsl:variable name="nodeEnd" select="$nodeSet[position() > 1]" />

        <!-- Perform computation for the current node -->
        <xsl:variable name="currSum">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$nodeStart/@encendido = '1'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(($nodeStart/@f div $f) * ($f div $n), '#0.0')" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="0" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <!-- Check whether the current node is not the last node in the node-set  -->
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($nodeEnd)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$sum + $currSum" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <!-- Recursive call to the same template -->
                <xsl:call-template name="ProductSum">
                    <xsl:with-param name="nodeSet" select="$nodeEnd" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="f" select="$f" />
                    <xsl:with-param name="sum" select="$sum + $currSum" />
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<summation>0.4</summation>
```

Here is a similar question with the solution showing the additional options of using `XSLT 2.0` and `XSLT 1.0 Extension Functions` for generating the summation.

[Add attributes value using foreach in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50266276/add-attributes-value-using-foreach-in-xslt/)

Comment: Thank you! You're the best, i didn't think that this would be so confused haha i thought it would be easier than you show me, whatever, thank's ! (I dont know how to use this plataform, so I dont know if I am replying your comment, I hope I am, if i not i'm sorry :( )